# System image of 7 and 10 on the same external drive?

Tags: windows-7, system-restore, windows-10

I have 7U and I have made a system image that I have stored on an external drive.  I'm thinking about upgrading to 10, but if I do, I'll probably make a system image of that also and possibly switch between the two until I decide which one I want, if that is possible.

The system image utility only keeps the most recent image created for 7.  If I upgrade to 10 and create an image, will the 10 overwrite the 7 if on the same external drive or can they co-exist since they are different operating systems?